# How can I enable uploading excel files?

Tags: functions, uploads

I have an old school user who wants to upload an excel file to our Wordpress page.

Basically, Wordpress does not allow this.

Upon

https://gist.github.com/robwent/e3bf00bafe7a00bc3d0c4dceabde4fca

I put the following into functions.php before the end "Includes":

```
function my_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {

    // New allowed mime types.
    $mimes['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_custom_mime_types', 9999 );
```

But upon uploading an .xls file I get an error message that due to security this is not allowed (re-translated from my native language).

Was this an attempt in the right direction? How can I make this work?

Comment: [Excel has multiple possible mime types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/974079). Did you check which one your document has?

Comment: @kero Now I checked at http://mime.ritey.com/ and it did give the above mime type.

Comment: did you found the solution? it is not working for me too.

Answer (score 4):

I think the proper filter would be [mime_types](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mime_types/) found [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.2/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L2401).

```
function wpse294198_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['xls|xlsx'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'wpse294198_mime_types' );
```

You can use command line tool `file` (linux|macOS) to see the mime type, e.g. `file --mime-type -b somefile.xls`

Comment: add_filters ruined the theme and nothing appeared on the screen. using add_filter (without ending s) didn't do this, but I still cannot upload xls files, it says for security reasons it does not allow uploading it

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but didn't work for me in the end

I allowed all the mime types via wp-config.php

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

You can create your custom restriction when the file is submitted. use `$_FILES` array and put your restriction on the extension of the file and type before upload.

Comment: Allowing everything is not recommended unless you don't care about security.

Answer (score 0):

The `upload_mimes` hook is correct, the mime-type is not (anymore?).

The following is working for WP 5.8.2

```
function my_upload_mimes( $mimes ) {
        return array_merge($mimes, array (
            'xls' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'csv' => 'text/csv'
        ));
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_upload_mimes' );
```